# Moving files from multiple Linux servers to a central windows storage server

Tags: linux, windows, backup, rsync

I have multiple Linux servers with limited storage space that create very big daily logs. I need to keep these logs but can't afford to keep them on my server for very long before it fills up. The plan is to move them to a central windows server that is mirrored.

I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to this. What I've considered so far are rsync and writing a script in python or something similar.

The ideal method of backup that I want is for the files to be copied from the Linux servers to the Windows server, then verified for size/integrity, and subsequently deleted from the Linux servers. Can rsync do that? If not, can anyone suggest a superior method?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using `rsyslog` on the linux servers to send logs elsewhere.  I don't believe you can configure it to delete logged lines with a verification step - I'm not sure you'd want to either.  Instead, you might be best off with an aggressive logrotate schedule + rsyslog.